# check image size before upload

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [checking image size before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270460/checking-image-size-before-upload)

I want to check image size before upload photo using JavaScript

- Max width = 1024px
- Max Hight = 800px

How can this be done?

```
<script>
<!-- HERE MY QUESTION -->
</script>    
<form name="forms" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return check();">        
    <input type="file" name="img_name" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />        
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270460/checking-image-size-before-upload

Comment: That is big class, i just need less then 5-8 lines to do it with small javascript code :)   Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the image until it has been uploaded to your server, or if you use Flash to do it.

On upload, you can use `list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])` for example, using PHP. If the dimensions exceed your specification, remove the file and alert the user.

Comment: That is php, i can use it but with javascript is better; because i don't want to send the image in php file while it size so big

Thank you for help :)

Comment: @user JavaScript can't access the images on the client machine. There would be some issues if they could :P